# Composite UI implementation in rails/ruby based framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soa, composite

For someone moving from single monolith application to service based approach, having a single unified/composite UI is bit tricky. One approach is to expose services functionalities through APIs and have a front end application (emberjs, rails, etc) to consume them. This approach segregates the front end and back end (service) hence the concept of a team owning entire service (both frontend and backend) is lost assuming front end app is owned by different team as it requires knowledge of entire frontend application and the services it interacts with. Another approach is [Composite Frontend Pattern](http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/composite-frontend/). It seems once we have front end setup, we can deploy the front end changes for each service as well thus the concept of team owning a service remains intact.

If the focus is on one team per service (including frontend), what are the alternatives? Is there any framework or implementation example in ruby for Composite Frontend Pattern?

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Composite Frontend Pattern is not a big thing on the internet, it's someone's personal invention.

I'm not sure whether i understand the term correctly, the link you provided gives very little information.

From what i can see, the solution is trivial. EmberJS that you mentioned allows organizing frontend into reusable [components](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/). Components represent self-contained portions of the page, typically a component is a certain UI element or structural block. I think it is exactly what your link means by [portlets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portlet).

Create a component for each API feature your service has, then show only needed blocks to users.

As for coding, different team members can be responsible for different components.

The same approach can be achieved with any other framework, not just Ember, and even with a traditional jQuery approach. It's more of a discipline than a technological thing: just make your code modular and you'll be fine.

PS Rails is a backend framework.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I'm looking for what you mentioned is possible with EmberJs given the components can be developed and deployed independently. 
Yes, rails is mostly used as backend framework, but because of team's familiarity with it, I was thinking of using it for front-end where model instead of talking to db would talk to remote services. 
Do you have any other recommendations or you think EmberJs is the right choice?

Comment: Need more info on your project and its requirements to recommend anything.

Comment: You were saying the same approach could be achieved with frameworks other than just Ember. Just wanted to know what those other frameworks are. I guess they are one of listed here http://codebrief.com/2012/01/the-top-10-javascript-mvc-frameworks-reviewed/

Comment: You have to tell me more about your project, your development workflow and what exactly you expect from that 'Composite Frontend Pattern'.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me. We are on the course of breaking our monolith rails app to multiple services with unified UI with the goal of having one team per service. We were thinking if we can have frontend application setup in such way that frontend component and the related service are owned by the same team meaning they develop, deploy and run it e.g. there could be a user service and associated user component/page to deal with users which is managed by the same team. This is just one approach that we are trying to evaluate and see if it is worth it. (continued in next comment)...

Comment: That's why I was referring to 'Composite Frontend Pattern' as it seems to do the same thing.
Next approach could be to have a team entirely dedicated to the frontend application. Once a functionality is made available from service via API, they consume it and display it accordingly in the UI which means the service team works on the functionality and make it available via API and it becomes frontend team's responsibility to integrate that to the application.
We are trying to find and evaluate possible ways on dealing with service based system while keeping single and unified UI.

Comment: So you're considering having multiple projects maintained by different teams and you want UI components from one project be effortlessly transferrable to other projects?

Comment: Backend of each project will be different but there will be single unified frontend that communicates to different backend projects.